# how to get the time needed for a function perl?

Tags: perl

I want to measure the time needed to do some function in perl. I used `Time::HiRes` but the time is unreadable. how can it be achieved easily?

the code is:

```
use Time::HiRes qw (time);
my $start = time;
my_function_here ();
my $time = time - $start;
printf "Time needed for my_function_here is: $time sec\n";

sub my_function_here {
    my $null = 1;
}
```

Comment: I believe you should elaborate on "unreadable". Perhaps you could paste a piece of code you tried? There's a lot of examples in Time::HiRes manpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean unreadable like `7.86781311035156e-06` this is because the function is too fast so the number is not simple like a regular float. You better use a loop before the function so it makes the number more human readable.

```
use Time::HiRes qw (time);
my $start = time;
foreach ( 1 ... 1000000 ){
    my_function_here ();
}
my $time = time - $start;
print "Time needed for my_function_here is: $time sec\n";

sub my_function_here {
    my $null = 1;
}
```

your code has `printf` where it has to be `print`

Comment: So How can I guess the number `1000000` so it won't exceed 1 second and won't be shorter than 0.09 second?

Comment: Using `printf` to print a string will work until the string has a `%` character in it.

Answer (score 6):

I use [Benchmark](https://metacpan.org/module/Benchmark) core Perl module for this kind of tasks:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw/:hireswallclock/;

my $td = timeit(1, 'my_function_here');

print "the code took: ",timestr($td),"\n";
#<-- the code took: 2.86102e-006 wallclock secs ( 0.00 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.00 CPU)

sub my_function_here {
    my $null = 1;
    #...
}
```

Comment: nice add. but the problem was with the foreach loop. so the number gives more sense to humans.

Comment: Just put the number of times you want to execute at the first parameter of timeit. In my example, it was 1, change it to 1000000 or whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

If you have a more complex case and want to profile your perl script to see where the most time is used, you should look into the awesome Devel::NYTProf (see for instance http://augustinalareina.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/getting-started-with-develnytprof/). It will tell you how often a function is called, how long an average call and all together took, etc...

This way you really see where you loose time, and can concentrate on the parts where optimizations actually could make sense and also measure any improvements (or even the opposite) you where making.

Hope this helps you,
 Christian